# How to set text-anchor: end; using iText7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, itext7

Im using iText7 for generating PDF from SVG files. After creating a PDF there is an issue with some of elements which changing their possitions on PDF document. After PDf document is created the value of text-anchor is not included.

SVG before export to PDF

[image: SVG before export to PDF]

SVG after export to PDF

[image: SVG after export to PDF]

Now i have to enable text-anchor: end;
I found in iText7 documentation ther is dedicated option for that:

[image: Text-anchor from documentation]

But i dont know how can i use it in my code.

**PdfGeneratorService.cs**

```
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Svg.Converter;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService;
using PdfConverterController.Helpers;

namespace PdfConverterController.Services
{
    public class PdfGeneratorService : IPdfGeneratorService
    {
        public byte[] GeneratePdfFromSvgFile(IFormFile svgFile, string colorMode)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(svgFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                string svgContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(svgFile.OpenReadStream());

                if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null && xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Name == "svg")
                {
                    using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(
                            new PdfWriter(pdfStream,
                            new WriterProperties().SetCompressionLevel(0)));

                        PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();
                        doc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);

                        XmlDocument modifiedXmlDocument = SvgColorTransformer.ApplyColorTransformation(xmlDocument, colorMode);
                        string modifiedSvgContent = modifiedXmlDocument.OuterXml;

                        foreach (string pageSvgContent in GeneratePages.GenerateSvgPages(modifiedSvgContent))
                        {
                            doc.AddNewPage();

                            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(doc.GetLastPage());

                            // Scale transformation
                            float scaleX = .704f; // Adjust as needed
                            float scaleY = .704f; // Adjust as needed

                            Rectangle pageRectangle = doc.GetLastPage().GetPageSize();
                            float svgWidth = pageRectangle.GetWidth() * scaleX;
                            float svgHeight = pageRectangle.GetHeight() * scaleY;
                            float translateX = (pageRectangle.GetWidth() - svgWidth) / 99;
                            float translateY = (pageRectangle.GetHeight() - svgHeight) / 90;

                            // Apply the scaling transformation to the canvas
                            canvas.ConcatMatrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, translateX, translateY);

                            SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(pageSvgContent, doc, 1);
                        }

                        doc.Close();

                        return pdfStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadRequestException("Invalid SVG format");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```